# Java Webapp could not connect mysql on openshift

Tags: java, mysql, web, openshift

I'm new openshift. I created Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0) application on openshift to host my webapp. Now I'm deploying my war file and I'm facing with an error.

My web app could not connect to mysql. Error as below:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'admink5J5aXX'@'127.x.x.x' (using password: YES)
```

And here is my config for connection:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.username}" />
</bean>
```

And there properties is:

```
db.username=admink5J5aXX
db.password=password
db.url=jdbc:mysql://127.x.x.x:3306/myapp
```

User, password and host were provided by OpenShift.

```
env | grep MYSQL
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT=3306
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST=127.x.x.x
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD=password
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_IDENT=redhat:mysql:5.5:0.2.20
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME=admink5J5aXX
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL=mysql://admink5J5aXX:password@127.x.x.x:3306/
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_VERSION=5.5
```

I try to change `db.url=jdbc:mysql://127.x.x.x:3306/myapp` to `db.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/myapp`, `db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myapp`, `jdbc:mysql://${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}/${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}` but I still got error and my webapp doesn't work.

Update:

```
mysql> select user, host from mysql.user;
+--------------+-------------+
| user         | host        |
+--------------+-------------+
| admink5J5aXX | %           |
| admink5J5aXX | 127.x.x.x   |
+--------------+-------------+
```

Is there anyone can address the root cause of this error? Please help! :(

Thanks in advance.

P/s: My English is not good

Comment: Are you able to ssh to your application (or use port forwarding) and access the mysql database with those same credentials?  Is this a scaled application?  Is the database you are trying to access part of the same application as the code?

Comment: Sorry for late response, @corey112358. I have come back from work. Yes, I'm able to ssh to my application and connected to mysql database when using port forward. My application is not scale. The database which I'm trying to access is a part of myapplication.

Comment: Your config for connection is using db.username as the password `<property name="password" value="${db.username}" />`; is this a typo in this question only or do you have the same deployed?

Comment: Oh no!! This is my mistake, it's same in deployed code. Thanks @JiriFiala so much.

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer then, to have this question closed. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a connection config error in this case; username is used as a password:

```
<property name="password" value="${db.username}" />
```

...should read:

```
<property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
```